# PySpark cannot infer timestamp even with timestampFormat

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, date-formatting

I have this json file

```json
{"created_at":"2022-01-02 12:17:43.399 UTC","updated_at":"2022-01-02 12:17:43.399 UTC"}
```

Trying to read it as

```py
read_df = spark \
            .read \
            .option("timestampFormat", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS 'UTC'") \
            .option("inferSchema", "true") \
            .json(path)
```

but the inferred schema gives me back

```
root
 |-- created_at: string (nullable = true)
 |-- updated_at: string (nullable = true)
```

I've tried to forced it via `withColumn("timestamp",to_timestamp(col("created_at"), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS 'UTC'"))` and it works.

I don't want to provide myself the schema but let infer it because I have different files with different schemas and want to re-use the function for reading.

I'm not sure what's wrong.

Spark versionL 3.3.2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The inference of timestamps has to enabled explictly ([docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-migration-guide.html#upgrading-from-spark-sql-30-to-301), [code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/ca2ddf3c2079dda93053e64070ebda1610aa1968/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/json/JSONOptions.scala#L169)):

> Since version 3.0.1, the timestamp type inference is disabled by default. Set the JSON option inferTimestamp to true to enable such type inference.

```python
read_df = spark \
            .read \
            .option("timestampFormat", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS 'UTC'") \
            .option("inferSchema", "true") \
            .option("inferTimestamp", "true") \
            .json(path)
```

returns two timestamp columns.

Comment: For how weird it is, it still doesn't work.

Comment: @Tizianoreica - this solution works for me with the sample record shared in your question

Comment: I do realize that problem could be that some of microseconds are Optional, sometimes is S, sometimes is SS and sometimes is SSS and I wonder if this could lead to a problem for infering the timestamp. I will accept the answer anyway since it seems it's a different issue right now.